# git svn rebase index file open failed : Invalid argument

Tags: git, git-svn

I use git-svn on windows for the first time , `git svn rebase` show error:

`fatal: index file open failed: Invalid argument`

Why it happened and how can i fix it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are using msysgit on windows, there is a [regression on msysgit1.8.4 for `git-svn`](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Regression-in-e02ca72-git-svn-rebase-is-broken-on-Windows-td7595959.html).
It seems to appear when executed in a CMD, not in a bash shell, so you can try that same command in a shell.

Or you can **[SubGit](http://subgit.com/)**, which is much more complete and robust tool for transitionning from svn to git repo. [Listen to his author at GitMinutes #22](http://episodes.gitminutes.com/2013/09/gitminutes-22-alexander-kitaev-about.html).

---

The regression is <del>in progress to be</del> fixed (currently -- October 2013 -- in the ['`next`' branch of the git repo](https://github.com/git/git/tree/next))
[Bas Bossink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/74198/bas-bossink) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19511044/git-svn-rebase-index-file-open-failed-invalid-argument/19511402?noredirect=1#comment31584550_19511402):

> I just verified that it is fixed in [git 1.8.5.2.msysgit.0](https://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list?can=3&q=portable)

See [commit 7fbd42](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7fbd422162f2b49bc06a29a063f519450165dc86), by [jiangxin](https://github.com/jiangxin):

> [Tvangeste](https://github.com/Tvangeste) found that the "`relative_path`" function could not work properly on Windows if "in" and "prefix" have DOS drive prefix (such as "C:/windows"). ([$gmane/234434](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Regression-in-e02ca72-git-svn-rebase-is-broken-on-Windows-td7595959.html))
>
> E.g., When execute: `test-path-utils`, `relative_path "C:/a/b" "D:/x/y"` should return "`C:/a/b`", but returns "`../../C:/a/b`", which is wrong.
>
> So make relative_path honor DOS drive prefix.

Comment: @amy yes, downgrading is one solution. This should be fixed in 1.8.5 hopefully.

Comment: @VonC I just verified that it is fixed in git 1.8.5.2.msysgit.0.

Comment: @BasBossink great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing this problem when using --separate-git-dir with working directory and git directory on separate drives (git on a network drive in my case). As a workaround I've confirmed that you can use mklink (run as admin) to map the target drive:
mklink /d "C:\temp\my-git-dir" "D:\my-git-repo\"

Then something like the following will produce a viable repo and working dir.
git clone --no-hardlinks repo_url --separate-git-dir=D:/my-git-repo C:/temp/my-working-dir