# Git Status: fatal: index file open failed: Invalid argument within cmd.exe

Tags: git, version-control, command-line, windows-7, cmd

Environment Data:

- **Git Version**: 1.8.4
- **Operating System**: Windows 7 Professional

I am running into an issue where I am attempting to issue a Git Status using the options --work-tree and --git-dir inside cmd.exe

When I run the following:

`git --work-tree=E:\Workspaces\company --git-dir=E:\Workspaces\company\.git status`

I receive the following:

*`fatal: index file open failed: Invalid argument`*

If I swap the **status** for a **fetch** then everything works flawlessly. The status however refuses to run within cmd.exe

If I run the command, modified slightly work within msysGit pathing expectations, it executes properly.

```
git --work-tree=/e/Workspaces/company --git-dir=/e/Workspaces/company/.git status
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe your first one would work if you escape your backslashes:

```
git --work-tree=E:\\Workspaces\\company --git-dir=E:\\Workspaces\\company\\.git status
```

### UPDATE

I got it, try this:

```
git --work-tree="E:\Workspaces\company" --git-dir="E:\Workspaces\company\.git" status
```

I tried this and it worked for me. My directory even had spaces in it :-)

### REAL UPDATE

It seems this is a regression that was introduced in 1.8.4 and you may have to downgrade to 1.8.3 for now until it is fixed and 1.8.5 is released. Or use bash in the meantime.

Here is a reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19511402/329928

And here is the issue on GitHub:

> Tvangeste found that the "`relative_path`" function could not work properly on Windows if "in" and "prefix" have DOS drive prefix (such as "C:/windows").
>
> E.g., When execute: `test-path-utils`, `relative_path "C:/a/b" "D:/x/y"` should return "`C:/a/b`", but returns "`../../C:/a/b`", which is wrong.
>
> So make relative_path honor DOS drive prefix.

Comment: Chris,

This does't resolve the problem. I have tried this once before thinking the same thing. However, the fact that it works with **FETCH** nullifies this logic.

Comment: But it works with forward slashes, you say? `git --work-tree=/e/Workspaces/company --git-dir=/e/Workspaces/company/.git status`

Comment: Inside msysGit it does which interprets the input from shell quite differently.

Comment: Hey @JesseRiddle, I was able to get it to work for me by using double quotes.

Comment: C:\Users\jzr>git --work-tree="E:\Workspaces\company" --git-dir="E:\Workspaces\company\.git" status
fatal: index file open failed: Invalid argument

Comment: Hey @JesseRiddle, congrats you found a bug. Check out my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new folder and paste your files there
Re add the remote origin and it should push well for you